# Read public key from file in keystore

Tags: java, keystore, public-key

Hi I want to extract public key from KeyStore using Java code

I am creating a keystore

```
keytool -genkey -alias mykeystore -keyalg RSA -keystore mykeystore.jks -keysize 2048
```

And exporting the public into another file

```
keytool -export -alias mykeystore -keystore mykeystore.jks -rfc -file publickey.cert
```

How can I get the Public Key String from keystore or the publickey.cert file using the Java code?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("/home/myuser/my-keystore/mykeystore.jks");
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        String password = "myuserpass";
        char[] passwd = password.toCharArray();
        keystore.load(is, passwd);
        String alias = "mykeystore";
        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, passwd);
        if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {
          // Get certificate of public key
          Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
          // Get public key
          PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

          String publicKeyString = Base64.encodeBase64String(publicKey
                    .getEncoded());
          System.out.println(publicKeyString);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then it is giving like

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAiG2FjSuXrraYuh0TyRNiUvVCyaFlb7VY9AFIMSDdcY0JgNF0c4YVQxYxUCbYzmkLZD/rrYMe/8nxkWV0TMz2Y7GnvichjtWHL1ui58uC0+RtFMkYJ+ftwt9qBy9hvb/rVFTsvT5/b6CQXD8a6bFveMUluQZISLCV7i11XYzp81+w6M7+2fJAwezIJnIrgwv1K9YDjWaToaNXe7hnzzy0s8AdkjTk197+hg8dRfbvkr8XAddNsEMPeUA5iY+5VEpRNI925ZT/dxnaABA0z6i4JbVjeLl8r7ySG9R/2w/j2G+/YSRQc9BmRHPa0tBgH7wvQM+WRwD9WmST+5qeBIfH3QIDAQAB
```

When I do `cat publickey.cert`, it shows this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

They keys are different, even in length. Why?

Answer (score 29):

You can find a solution by just googleling for your question.

Example from java2s.com:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("your.keystore");

    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keystore.load(is, "my-keystore-password".toCharArray());

    String alias = "myalias";

    Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, "password".toCharArray());
    if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {
      // Get certificate of public key
      Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);

      // Get public key
      PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

      // Return a key pair
      new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key);
    }
  }
}
```

See also:

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/RetrievingaKeyPairfromaKeyStore.htm
- [How to retrieve my public and private key from the keystore we created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937890/how-to-retrieve-my-public-and-private-key-from-the-keystore-we-created)

**UPDATE:**

See comments for additional information to the problem.

Comment: @iProgrammer Hi, to answer the question at the end of your question: The difference is, that the publickey.cert is a whole certificate and not only the key itself. It also contains a lot of additional information. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate#Contents_of_a_typical_digital_certificate

Comment: I got that. But see the public Key I got from java code and the public key in the public.cert file. Just check first few characters, you can understand both are different.

Comment: Please check the Java code also. Thanks. Anything wrong there?

Comment: It is exactly like I already told you. A Certificate contains a lot of additional information which are also encoded in base64. Take that output you provided (the ----BEGIN CERT----- one), paste it into a text file. Save that file and rename the file to something.cert. You get the WHOLE certificate including all additional fields and not only the public key. This is why you can't compare those two strings. They are just different - even in a logical way.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.Base64;

//=====================

try {
    File file = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\keyStoreFilehere.kstr");
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    String password = "password";
    keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
    Enumeration enumeration = keystore.aliases();
    while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
         String alias = (String)enumeration.nextElement();
         Certificate certificate = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
         PublicKey publicKey = keystore.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey();
         byte[] encodedCertKey = certificate.getEncoded();
         byte[] encodedPublicKey = publicKey.getEncoded();
         String b64PublicKey = Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(encodedPublicKey);
         String b64CertKey = Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(encodedCertKey);
         String publicKeyString = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
                            + b64PublicKey
                            + "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

         String certKeyString = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
                            + b64CertKey
                            + "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
         System.out.println(publicKeyString);
         System.out.println(certKeyString);
    }

 } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException  | KeyStoreException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 6):

The first base 64 contains only the key

```
Base64.encodeBase64String(publicKey.getEncoded())
```

The second base 64 contains the whole public certificate

```
Base64.encodeBase64String(cert.getEncoded())
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's just the public key string that you want, it's easier to get the `publickey.cert` file, as it is a plain text file. Assuming that you have the full path of the file (like "/home/users/iprogrammer/publickey.cert" or "D:\MyDocuments\publickey.cert" )  you do something like:

```
public String getPublicKeyString( Path path ) throws IOException {
    byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return new String( fileBytes, "US-ASCII" );
}
```

This will give you the whole file, including the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.

Once you have the whole file, you can use the BouncyCastle library to open it:

```
    PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(certPEMData));
    Object parsedObj = pemParser.readObject();
    System.out.println("PemParser returned: " + parsedObj);
    if (parsedObj instanceof X509CertificateHolder)
    {
        X509CertificateHolder x509CertificateHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) parsedObj;
        return x509CertificateHolder.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo().getPublicKeyData().getString();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("The parsed object was not an X509CertificateHolder.");
    }
```

Comment: Then I can read the whole file. There are Java security functions to read public key from keystore

Comment: You asked for the public key string. Of course there are ways to read from the key store. But since you already exported it, I gave you the way to read it.

Comment: Actually, if he can read the Certificate in as a String like that, then he could use the `PEMParser` class from Bouncycastle.

Comment: @Zhuinden, yes, but then he'll get the public key as an `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` object. Frankly, I would not have given the answer I've given if he didn't specifically ask for the public key **String**.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the KeyStore loaded, it's one simple line to get the PublicKey.

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    ks.load(null);          
    PublicKey publicKey = ks.getCertificate("aliasYouChose").getPublicKey();
```

The PublicKey is located 'inside' the Certificate, the Certficate is not just the PublicKey.

Also, it's important to note that a properly formatted PEM key expects a "\n" after every 64 characters.  So, simply putting "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----" at the end (and respective beginning) might not work if you're trying to then use it with openSSL in PHP, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have successfully exported , you can get it from the key store,

through `KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key)`

An example ,

```
   FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("publickey.cert");
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keystore.load(is, "my-keystore-password".toCharArray());
    String alias = "myalias";
    Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, "password".toCharArray());
    if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {
      // Get certificate of public key
      Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
      // Get public key
      PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

      // Return a key pair
      new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key);
    }
  }
```

will return the new *key,value* pair.

Also read the similar thread here [Get Private Key from Keystore](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-can-i-export-my-private-key-from-a-java-keytool-keystore)

Comment: sorry i cant the second part in your update can you be more clear

Comment: Please see the public Key I got from Java code and the public key in the public.cert file. Just check first few characters, you can understand both are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the string version of the PublicKey:

`String publicKeyString value = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
    + new String(Base64.encode(publicKey.getEncoded()))
    + "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";`