# I am getting BadPaddingException while decrypting an 128 bit AES key which has been encoded by using RSA generated public key(.jks)

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa, badpaddingexception

```java
package demo123;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
```

// Java 8 example for RSA-AES encryption/decryption.

public class AESwithRSA {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String plainText = "{\"scope\":\"payments\",\"x-mig-bank\": \"ICICI\",\"x-mig-channel\": \"RC\",\"tpp_redirect_uri\": \"www.tpp-app.com?query=123\",\"x-tpp-client-id\": \"Ck234567890112\",\"tpp-app-name\": \"amazon\",\"Consent Id\": \"d25a6f26-3ad5-4dd8-96fd-2582abfa3f58\",\"Type\": \"Domestic Payment\" }";
```

// Generate public and private keys using RSA

```
    Key privateKey = getPrivate("KeyPair/privateKey.jks");
    System.out.println("Private key success");
    System.out.println("Private key :" + privateKey);
    Key publicKey = getPublic("KeyPair/publicKey.");
    System.out.println("Public key success");
    System.out.println("Public key :" + publicKey);
```

// First create an AES Key

```
    String secretAESKeyString = getSecretAESKeyAsString();
    System.out.println("Secret Key "+secretAESKeyString);
```

// Encrypt our data with AES key

```
    String encryptedText = encryptTextUsingAES(plainText, secretAESKeyString);
    System.out.println("Encrypted text "+encryptedText);
```

// Encrypt AES Key with RSA Private Key

```
    byte[] encryptedAESKeyString = encryptAESKey(secretAESKeyString, publicKey);
    System.out.println("Encrypted AES key with RSA "+encryptedAESKeyString);
```

// First decrypt the AES Key with RSA Public key

```
    String decryptedAESKeyString = decryptAESKey(encryptedAESKeyString, privateKey);
    System.out.println("Decrypted AES key with RSA "+decryptedAESKeyString);
```

// Now decrypt data using the decrypted AES key!

```
    String decryptedText = decryptTextUsingAES(encryptedText, decryptedAESKeyString);
```

//Showing all the outputs

```
    System.out.println("input: " + encryptedText);
    System.out.println("AES Key: " + secretAESKeyString);
    System.out.println("decrypted: " + decryptedText);
    System.out.println("Text New:" + textNew);
    System.out.println("Encrypted New:" + encryptedTextNew);
    //System.out.println("Decrypted New:" + decryptedTextNew);

}
```

// Create a new AES key. Uses 128 bit (weak)

```
public static String getSecretAESKeyAsString() throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    generator.init(128); // The AES key size in number of bits
    SecretKey secKey = generator.generateKey();
    String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secKey.getEncoded());
    return encodedKey;
}
```

// Encrypt text using AES key

```
public static String encryptTextUsingAES(String plainText, String aesKeyString) throws Exception {
    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(aesKeyString);
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");

    // AES defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java 7
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
    byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteCipherText);
}
```

// Decrypt text using AES key

```
public static String decryptTextUsingAES(String encryptedText, String aesKeyString) throws Exception {

    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(aesKeyString);
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");

    // AES defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java 7
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
    byte[] bytePlainText = aesCipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText));
    return new String(bytePlainText);
}
```

// Encrypt AES Key using RSA private key

```
private static byte[] encryptAESKey(String plainAESKey, Key publicKey ) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    return Base64.getEncoder().encode(cipher.doFinal(plainAESKey.getBytes()));
}
```

// Decrypt AES Key using RSA public key

```
private static String decryptAESKey(byte[] encryptedAESKey, Key privateKey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedAESKey)));
}
```

//Getting public and private .jks format key

```
public static Key getPrivate(String filename) throws Exception {
        String password = "123456";
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
        String alias = "rib_pub_priv_ob";
        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());        
        return key;
    }

    // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html
    public static Key getPublic(String filename) throws Exception {
        String password = "123456";
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
        String alias = "tmsx_pub_priv_ob";
        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());        
        return key;
    }
```

}

//Following is the output

```
Private key success
Private key :sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl@ffd2dcac
Public key success
Public key :sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl@fff19d78
Secret Key XsZue3ATt4OAQFP5C4sa8Q==
Encrypted text mjynBmIDhsj9L3jhFmzb4CFaJr+i5k2B1luuTdg0ls3NoAvI3wLfeU54Sxo7IDBrqH3i3F3RNM4DDPhWdbtEMNQ+27EcQOugidB2BcTFigzIImNohZOVjBi+qrPC7KWGLf9JWlJHUsoUz+oKiuAJGjitrrIMg/qQN7He87hH6hxfNZ7vceZV2N6HihYsQ4R1S6YFRUDVBwuG+IjvEyzihkw4mmlmjq4FIspXmaYuxYE/6urevUD/dY7HSLVrVRst83VRKnqDrzf32RolGsM12Ebyk0XJGGOYHV/OWfYExkaQdfUaEVMhU3h/tTmSoVJHEHTf1YdMxv5x/HZd2aXoYw==
Encrypted AES key with RSA [B@5f150435
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at demo123.AESwithRSA.decryptAESKey(AESwithRSA.java:135)
    at demo123.AESwithRSA.main(AESwithRSA.java:60)
```

Comment: My answer was wrong, so deleted. Regardless that I have to add a few notes to avoid some weaknesses:  Do not use ECB mode, any other would do, use explicit algorithm declaration such as `AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding`, use some sort of integrity check such as HMAC or GCM mode, no need to always base64 encode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by loading in `getPublic` the *private* key instead of the *public* key. This can be easily seen in the output: For both keys, objects of the type `sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl` are displayed, whereas the public key should actually be of the type `sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl`. To load the public key in `getPublic` replace the line

```
Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
```

by

```
Key key = keystore.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey();
```

See also [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26711907)[[2]](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/RetrievingaKeyPairfromaKeyStore.htm). With this fix the code works on my machine.

*Update:* In the current code, the Base64-encoded AES key (from `getSecretAESKey`) is encrypted with RSA and this key is then again Base64-encoded (in `encryptAESKey`). Such a double Base64-encoding is actually not necessary, as it would be sufficient to encrypt the *raw* AES key with RSA, as each Base64-encoding has a 33% overhead.