# Java Keystore in project

Tags: java, keystore

Want to store secret key by java keystore .

As JDK maintain keystore in jre\lib\security\cacerts & have doubt on below point

Could anybody clear doubt over here
1) where exactly the .keystore file stored , is it in project itself as like of config file or in jdk folder i.e security folder
2) Do we need to provide the certificate for our custom created key  ? if yes then how can we give with java code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out what keystore my JVM is using?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980364/how-do-i-find-out-what-keystore-my-jvm-is-using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing two types of stores. `cacerts` is a truststore; you need a keystore.  In short, roughly, the truststore is who you trust and the keystore is who you are.

Using an X.509 certificate is the correct way to manage a private key (such as with SSL).  You can specify certificates through properties passed to Java when starting your application (be it a standalone application or a container like Tomcat) or programmatically. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5871352/185034) provides a concise overview of the properties required to configure your keystore and truststore.  You probably won't have to do anything with the truststore.

Comment: Thanks Paul...Got your point that we do not have to take anything from cacerts. as this jdk truststore where jdk store his key..Please correct me if I am wrong at any place... But what about our private key where it will go that's the only things I am bit confuse about ... Do we have to make keystore and store in trusttore i.e security/cancerts

Comment: No, the keystore is a separate entity.  You make a keystore and then tell Java about it.  Read the link in my answer; it explains the properties required. It might help to know what you are trying to do with your private key. Is it for SSL or client authentication or something else?

Comment: It is just my secret key want to store and no one gone use this except me...definalty it will load through java code

Comment: SecretKey secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
  System.out.println("Stored Key:\t" + secretKey);
  //store the secret key
  KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry keyStoreEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey);
  // Password to store key file
  PasswordProtection keyPassword = new PasswordProtection("PASSWORD_FOR_PROTECTION_OF_FILE".toCharArray());
  /** Storing in key value format like map but with password */
   keyStore.setEntry("MAP_KEY", keyStoreEntry, keyPassword);
  keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(keyStoreFile), "PASSWORD_FOR_KEYSTORE_FILE".toCharArray());

Comment: If you want to retrieve your public and private key from a Java keystore see the answers to this question: [How to retrieve my public and private key from the keystore we created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937890/how-to-retrieve-my-public-and-private-key-from-the-keystore-we-created)