# Private Key is coming as Null from Keystore Object

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle, keystore

Below is my code for getting private key from Keystore file.

```
BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.addProvider(provider);
System.err.println(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/xxx.jks"), PASSWORD);
String alias = "xxxxxxx";
PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, PASSWORD);
System.err.println(pk);
```

I am giving right values for alias and password. But I am getting null in private key.

Why I am getting null, Is there any alternative approach to get private key from jks file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

My question is not able to get the private key. But the mentioned question is the incorrect key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve my public and private key from the keystore we created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937890/how-to-retrieve-my-public-and-private-key-from-the-keystore-we-created)

Comment: The [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getKey-java.lang.String-char:A-) tell you the answer: "Returns:
    the requested key, **or null if the given alias does not exist or does not identify a key-related entry.**". Believe it.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, Thanks, I checked the alias name exists by keystore.conatinsAlias("xxx") it returns true only. I have verified in linux also.

Comment: "...or does not identify a key-related entry". See [`isKeyEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html#isKeyEntry(java.lang.String))

Comment: @JamesKPolk, yes you are correct. I have created new jks file and tried now I am getting the private key. So my previous jks file has no key related entry so only i am getting null. Thanks for your guidance.