# ssl weblogic with identity keystore

Tags: ssl, https, weblogic, ssl-certificate, weblogic11g

I can't make my weblogic 11g to work on https. The problem is with identity keystore. How should I create identity keystore? I have private key, web server certificate and intermediate certificate in pem format. I import private key and certificates like this:

```
keytool -import -keystore myIdentity.jks -storepass mypass -storetype JKS -alias myPrivateKey -file mykey.pem -keypass mypass

keytool -import -keystore myIdentity.jks -storepass mypass -storetype JKS -alias mycert -trustcacerts -file certificate.pem -keypass mypass
```

I am dummy at this and don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate the IdentityStore :

*keytool -genkey -keystore myIdentityStore.jks -storepass welcome1 -alias dummy -dname CN="dummy,C=FR" -keypass welcome1*

2. Import certificates in the TrustStore

*keytool -import -v -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias myCertificateAliasName -file myCertificateLocation -keystore myTrustStore.jks -storepass welcome1*

3. Configure your weblogic Server :

Environment -> Servers – AdminServer -> Keystores, then
Change Demo Identity and Demo Trust to Custom Identity and Custom Trust.

Also, change those values for Identity

Custom Identity Keystore : $OSB_HOME/vesiKeyStore/vesiIdentityStore.jks, 
Custom Identity Keystore Type : JKS,
Confirm Custom Identity Keystore Passphrase :welcome1.

Do the same for Trust.

4. restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Found very useful:
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/importing-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-use-i)

I generated keystore with IBM Keyman and solved my problems.