# Import key and SSL Certificate into java keystore

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have certificate file and private key file in pem format. Is it possible to load these files into Java keystore using Java code with default libraries that comes with JDK and not with third party libraries. When I tried googling, I am able to find only files which are in .der format to import into java keystore using java code.

http://knowledge-oracle.blogspot.in/2009/02/import-private-key-and-certificate-in.html

Is it possible to load key and certificate file which is in pem format into java keystore through java code without converting to .der format ?

Comment: For those who just want to do this manually and not programmatically, you can use openssl and keytool:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/importing-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-use-i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible but not without using third-party libraries.
Java does not use pem format for keystore containers as OpenSSL does so you will have to convert these into a keystore either `PKCS12` or `JKS`.
You can do the conversion by code using bouncy castle or you could use a tool to create a keystore from the pem file and use the keystore in your application.
Try this java application [Certificate Helper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/certhelper/) to do the conversion to keystore

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small utility program what can import pem files:
       http://www.clearfield.com/key_store_browser/key_store_browser.html

This utility is opensource, you can download the source code.

Comment: Unfortunately link 404.