# Configuring SSL for Tomcat 7 leads to an ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https

I followed the following steps to setup SSL for Tomcat 7, after downloaded my certificates from my CA, I:

1. used Java keytool to import root, intermediate, and my site certificate into local keystore.
2. modified tomcat server.xml file to this (many sites are having the similar conf):

   ```
   <Connector
    port="8443"
    SSLEnabled="true"
    protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    maxThreads="150"
    scheme="https"
    secure="true"
    keystoreFile="conf/.keystore"
    keystorePass="password"
    clientAuth="false"
    sslProtocol="TLS"
    />
   ```

Everything seemed fine until I opened browser to access the site and got an ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error in Chrome, and "no common encryption algorithm" error under Firefox.

I spent a few hours but yet could not figure out what the problem is, and would be grateful to those who can shed light on this issue.

**UPDATE**
It works now after keystoreFile changes to .pfx file, but why does not it work by following java keystore (.keystore) with importing .cer files approach?

Comment: Can you specify what you did to convert the keystore file to .pfx file, and how you got this to work? I have similar problem with JBoss server, and I want to try your approach.

Comment: The settings for the pfx are described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271327/installing-updated-pfx-wildcard-into-tomcat-keystore

Comment: This can happen if you don't have a private key in the keystore.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I forgot to import the private key. Follow the instructions in this thread[1] to import your and the CA's certificate and your private key. That worked for me.

[1] [importing an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/importing-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-use-i)

Comment: Thanks, this helped - obvious mistake. ;-)