# Installing a PFX wildcard for SSL usage into Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl

I have the exact situation stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271327/installing-updated-pfx-wildcard-into-tomcat-keystore). I am using Apache Tomcat 8.5 and have inserted these lines into my server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:/Program Files/certs/mycert.pfx" 
keystorePass="myPassword" keystoreType="PKCS12"/>
```

After I start my server I receive the following error which I am unable to solve.

...

```
23-Mar-2017 11:01:07.776 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.10 using APR version 1.5.2.
23-Mar-2017 11:01:07.776 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
23-Mar-2017 11:01:07.776 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
23-Mar-2017 11:01:08.870 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016)
23-Mar-2017 11:01:09.120 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
23-Mar-2017 11:01:09.260 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
23-Mar-2017 11:01:09.276 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-8443"]
23-Mar-2017 11:01:09.776 WARNING [main] 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.init Error initializing SSL context
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLContext.init(OpenSSLContext.java:281)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:85)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:226)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:941)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:237)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:558)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:968)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

23-Mar-2017 11:01:09.776 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
```

....

The certificate was generated from an authority. I was only given the .pfx file and the password. I know the password is correct because I can use openssl to access the certifcate. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
This is technically not an answer since it does not fix the use of the .pfx file and the password.

I used keytool with these commands:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mycert.pfx 
-srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore mynewcert.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

I answered the questions and keytool made mynewcert.jks and gave me a GUID.

I then changed my server.xml to the following:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:/Program Files/certs
/mynewcert.jks" keystorePass="myPassword" />
```

I restart the server and it produced the same exact error as I received before. So then I added the following to the server.xml:

```
keyAlias="GUID I got from keytool"
```

Now everything is working.

Answer (score 4):

I know that the question is from 2017 but I had the same problem and I think that maybe someone will find the same issue.

The problem, as you say, is the keyAlias. You can get your alias from your pfx file using this on you cmd:

```
keytool -list -v -storetype pkcs12 -keystore certificado_mmkt_.pfx
```

[Alias name in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di27R.png)

There you can find a field called "Alias name". Add the field keyAlias in the Connector. In my case keyAlias is 1.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:/Program Files/certs/mycert.pfx" 
keystorePass="myPassword" keystoreType="PKCS12" keyAlias="1"/>
```