# No name matching graph.facebook.com found (SSLHandshakeException/CertificateException)

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

At our QC server we have done the following steps:

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -out server.csr -key server.key
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt

openssl pkcs12 -export -in server.crt -inkey server.key -out server.p12 -name some-alias   -CAfile ca.crt -caname root

keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit 
-destkeystore server.keystore -srckeystore server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass 
changeit -alias server
```

(The CAfile never got created, so have not used it yet.)

These steps were done based on SO references:

> 1/[importing an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/importing-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-use-i/8224863#8224863)
>
> 2/[Trust Store vs Key Store - creating with keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340918/trust-store-vs-key-store-creating-with-keytool)

Further, I have used/tested the SSLPoke utility from Altassian(https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/180292346/SSLPoke.java?version=1&modificationDate=1236556497004&api=v2)  and the same seems to work with the following command on the same server:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=server.keystore 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.debug=all  SSLPoke 
facebook.com 443
```

The problem is with apache+tomcat, which is throwing the said exception when a connection to https://graph.facebook.com is made via java code.

How can I overcome this exception?

Here is the listing of the facebook certificat in the server.keystore:

```
#keytool -list -v -keystore server.keystore -alias facebook.com
Enter keystore password:  
Alias name: facebook.com
Creation date: 17 Jun, 2014
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=*.facebook.com, O="Facebook, Inc.", L=Menlo Park, ST=CA, C=US
Issuer: CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Serial number: 771430e2db21fb0b295cdb959c98454
Valid from: Sat Mar 01 05:30:00 IST 2014 until: Mon Apr 13 17:30:00 IST 2015
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  D3:A6:3C:18:15:C6:4B:BB:BE:75:7B:AC:ED:7D:2B:80
     SHA1: BD:01:2A:89:B2:CC:9E:49:F8:1F:47:BF:BD:52:DE:48:A0:4E:D3:AB
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: A4 5F 2C 39 02 78 AE 38   57 D1 42 5D 3B 43 CE 4F  ._,9.x.8W.B];C.O
0010: AF F0 97 72                                        ...r
]
]

#4: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.digicert.com, 
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2
   accessLocation: URIName: http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertHighAssuranceCA-3.crt]
]

#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl3.digicert.com/ca3-g27.crl]
, DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://crl4.digicert.com/ca3-g27.crl]
]]

#6: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.16.840.1.114412.1.1]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
  qualifier: 0000: 16 1C 68 74 74 70 73 3A   2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 64 69  ..https://www.di
0010: 67 69 63 65 72 74 2E 63   6F 6D 2F 43 50 53        gicert.com/CPS

]]  ]
]

#7: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

#8: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 50 EA 73 89 DB 29 FB 10   8F 9E E5 01 20 D4 DE 79  P.s..)...... ..y
0010: 99 48 83 F7                                        .H..
]

]

#9: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: *.facebook.com
  DNSName: facebook.com
  DNSName: *.fbsbx.com
  DNSName: *.fbcdn.net
  DNSName: *.xx.fbcdn.net
  DNSName: *.xy.fbcdn.net
]
#
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that we had a firewall issue.

Our QC server was under blocked IP's for facebook.
An SSLPoke to google showed no error, while the same to facebook showed invalid certificate due to the ping being returned from the internal firewall, and hence the certificate exception for graph.facebook.com, name not found.