# Getting "No certificate matches private key"

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, keytool

### This is the sequence of commands I tried:

a. Extract an existing certificate key from the store:

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore -srcalias one -destkeystore temppp -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass passwordd -deststorepass passwordd
```

b. Extract the private key from the exported certificate:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in temppp -out csr_private.key -nocerts -nodes -password pass:passwordd
```

c. Generate csr using extracted key:

```
openssl req -nodes -sha256 -new -key csr_private.key -out request.csr -subj '/C=IL/ST=Unknown/L=Unknown/O=Bla/OU=Bla/CN=BLAAAA'
```

d. Generate a self-signed certificate and key:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ca_key.pem -nodes -sha512 -days 4096 -subj '/C=IL/ST=Unknown/L=Unknown/O=Bla Bla/OU=BLA/CN=FOOO' -out ca.pem
```

e. Sign the csr with the self-signed certificate:

```
openssl x509 -in request.csr -out signed_cert.pem -req -signkey ca_key.pem -days 1001
```

f. Export the signed certificate and csr key to one p12 file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in signed_cert.pem -inkey csr_private.key -out file.p12 -name "one"
```

### Result:

**No certificate matches private key**

1. What am I missing? Why isn't my last command legitimate?
2. I planned to do "keytool -importkeystore" file.p12 (that should have been generated in the last step) to replace the "one" privateKeyEntry in "keystore". As suggested in *[How to import an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/importing-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-use-i)*.
   Basically I'm trying to edit that entry to have the same key, but a different certificate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fix is to add "-nodes" to the last command (f).
In the second command that key was exported with "-nodes" (no DES encryption), and it should be the same in the last command too.