# Java Client/Server SSL Socket Chat

Tags: java, sockets, openssl, client, serversocket

Ok pals, so I have created a java chat using TCP client/server socket.
I create the server, and then i create clients that connect to the server so that they can communicate between each other through the server!
The code: Server:

```
public ServerChat() throws Exception{
    ServerSocket soc=new ServerSocket(5217);


    while(true)
    {    
        Socket CSoc=soc.accept();        
        //and then the code for handling the messages, we don't need that 

    }
}
```

And the client:

```
 Server soc=new Socket("127.0.0.1",5217);
Thread t=new Thread(this);
t.start();
//i Have ommited many parts of the code, but you know, i focus on the connection part of the problem!`
```

So now, I want to use SSL protection(so i can see the changes in wireshark).
I used OpenSSL(it is required for my assingment) to create a root CA and device certificates.I put the files on the src folder on netbeans, and copied the code to two new classes, SSLServer and SSLClient, and experimented a bit on the SSL part! So:

```
public SSLServer() throws Exception{
SSLContext sslContext=????//supposed to add the files somehow here? 
SSLServerSocketFactory factory=(SSLServerSocketFactory)slContext.getServerSocketFactory();
SSLServerSocket sslserversocket=(SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(1234);
while(true)
{   
SSLSocket sslsocket=(SSLSocket)sslserversocket.accept();                
}
}
```

Same thing for the client. So I am a bit stuck on the SSLContext part! I read many threads here but still..
Is the part below SSLContext correct? And how do I use the certificates in SSLContext?
EDIT: Maybe this will work? :

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("keystoreFile"), "keystorePassword".toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
kmf.init(ks, "keystorePassword".toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509"); 
tmf.init(ks);

SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); 
TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers(); 
sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustManagers, null); 

SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory(); 
SSLServerSocket s = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(serverport);
SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) s.accept();
```

Answer (score 1):

anyway, i found some links that helped me!
if anyone is interested,

[importing an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/importing-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-use-i)

http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/79-AB.html