# Configuring SSL on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, certificate, keystore

I am trying to configure tomcat7 on server with SSL because I need to send a request via https://

I am following steps -:

```
               1.Create a keystore file using Java
               2.Configure Tomcat to use the keystore
```

I tried to create a keystore directly with

```
          keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

and then tried to access https://[host]:8443 it worked

But when I tried to create keystore with the .cer file

```
        keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias server -file your_site_name.p7b -keystore your_site_name.jks
```

Also used

```
         keytool -import -alias simple -file Example.cer -keystore exampleraystore
```

and tried to access https://[host]:8443 it is not working .. showing "WEB PAGE CAN"T BE DISPLAYED"

why

Comment: whenever I use .p7b file it gives an error that its not a X509 certificate .

Comment: so I used .cer file to create the certificate in second step

Answer (score 0):

- Do you use self signed certificate, or signed by external CA ?
- Did you modify server.xml as said in [tomcat doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File)  ?
- Does simple self signed cert work, and only imported from your_site_name.p7b doesn't work ?

If simple self signed certificate doesn't work try

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30192138/1423685

it helped me.

Comment: Its a self assigned Certificate in first try and in second try I used .cer file to create the key store , yeah I did modify server.xml that's why its working when I tried to create keystore directly ,yeah self signed is working

Answer (score 0):

> But when I tried to create keystore with the .cer file

```
    keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias server
```

... you were doing something invalid. This creates a truststore, not a keystore. There is no private key there. If you were attempting to import a signed certificate, you should have omitted the `-trustcacerts` flag, and used the same alias you used when generating the keypair and CSR.

This is all stated clearly by example in the Tomcat SSL documentation.

Comment: Followed you and created keystore using

Comment: keytool -import -alias simple -file Example.cer -keystore mykeystore

Answer (score -1):

Did you change your server.xml to redirect to port 8443?

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               port="8080" redirectPort="8443"

<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               port="8443"
               SSLEnabled="true"
               scheme="https" 
               secure="true"
               sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystorePass="<pass>" keystoreFile="<path to keystore>"
               ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, <add more ciphers>"/>
```

Comment: He puts https and 8443 port explicitly into url, so it shouldnt be the case. Adding ciphers do may help.

Comment: As he already had it working the answer to this is clearly 'yes'.