# SSL websockets proxy via nginx proxy with client auth

Tags: java, ssl, nginx, https, proxy

I'm having trouble setting up a reverse proxy through nginx to a websocket application with client certificate authentication; so far I've gotten the server SSL cert to work no problem. Here are my steps so far for the client auth:

Create the client cert:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
openssl genrsa -out client.key 1024
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey \
  ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt
```

Configure nginx:

```
daemon off;
events {
  worker_connections 4096;
}

http {
  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
  }

  server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    server_name rserve;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
    # ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ca.crt;
    # ssl_verify_client on;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
  }
}
```

If I enable the ssl client stuff things stop working. On the client I'm using a jetty implementation (java), I import the client cert into a keystore with this line:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore keystore.jks \
  -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias client -file client.crt
```

This procedure worked for a selfsigned server cert. The failure is reported on the client as a failure to switch protocols, this is in line with my previous failures on behalf of the SSL handshake - the proxied application is websocket only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the private key outside of the keystore and have now imported just the certificate. The client application needs access to both the private and public parts.

Either [import the private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/importing-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-use-i) or generate the certificate signing request using `keytool` rather than `openssl`.