# Unable to Load an X509Certificate into an XML Digital Signature

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature

I'm using JDK 1.8.0_74.

I have code for creating an XML Digital Signature based on a standard way of doing things (e.g. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html).

However, instead of loading a key store and key for the X509Data element of the signature block, I simply want to load an X509Certificate as part of the signature block, which would yield something like this:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#body">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>d6xssQEvw9mMXEbQ1+/jpYTFbqY=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>HwQ5o5RzCauJSIcyGyzPlIJHMYtaA2spBmnRvTmcL0S+bfb/UovUwBAn7WAKckUH
Qv0TuRMMZG3xaV5h4tdrW3hgSw1wZFfEG9cxViz6cr7FOTOEfOAjtU3M8v2/f21i
4o7w5ZORwAlUONamQ0C9x5CNccvNZln5vrpdcL+vqSc=</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<X509Certificate xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">MIIC9TCCAl6gAwIBAgICFNAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEEBQAwgYcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlpB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</X509Certificate>
<X509IssuerSerial xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<X509IssuerName>CN=Thawte Test CA Root,OU=TEST TEST TEST,O=Thawte Certification,ST=FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY,C=ZA</X509IssuerName>
<X509SerialNumber>5328</X509SerialNumber>
</X509IssuerSerial>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
```

(BTW, this is a valid signature that I've verified previously.)

Now, I have code that looks like this:

```
javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
        List x509Content = new ArrayList();

        X509Certificate certObj1 = null;

        try {
            InputStream fis = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.cert");
            certObj1 = (X509Certificate)(X509Certificate.getInstance(fis));
            fis.close();
            fis = null;                       
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (javax.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        

        x509Content.add(certObj1);
        x509Content.add(certObj1.getSubjectDN().getName());

        javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
        javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));
```

But, when this line is executed:

```
javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: content[0] is not a valid X509Data type
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMX509Data.<init>(DOMX509Data.java:90)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMKeyInfoFactory.newX509Data(DOMKeyInfoFactory.java:106)
    at com.abc.service.TestService.generateSignature(TestService.java:33...
```

Having looked through the appropriate code (both online and in the actual .class file decompiled), it fails in this section of the DOMX509Data constructor:

```
if (x509Type instanceof String) {
                new X500Principal((String)x509Type);
            } else if (!(x509Type instanceof byte[]) &&
                !(x509Type instanceof X509Certificate) &&
                !(x509Type instanceof X509CRL) &&
                !(x509Type instanceof XMLStructure)) {
                throw new ClassCastException
                    ("content["+i+"] is not a valid X509Data type");
            }
```

But, if I copy/paste and recreate that same code in my own code, that exception NEVER happens!

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this might be.  I've checked that the type of `content[0]` is `com.sun.security.cert.internal.x509.X509V1CertImpl` which most definitely extends `X509Certificate`.

What am I doing wrong?  I'm hoping I've overlooked something or I'm doing something wholly illegal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

While I'd still like to know why this is, in the interest time of time, I've followed the example here (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html) and it loads in the certificate body itself, but you first have to convert the cert into a keystore (this might help: [importing an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/importing-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-use-i)).

Also, if you just want to load the serial info instead of the certificate body itself, try something like this:

```
String dn = cert.getIssuerDN().toString();
BigInteger sn = cert.getSerialNumber();
X509IssuerSerial xd = kif.newX509IssuerSerial(dn, sn);

// next commented line was the original, replaced with the above line    
//javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(kif.newX509Data(Collections.singletonList(xd))));
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little to late but might help someone one day.

I was facing the same error and in my case I was passing the wrong alias. To find the alias, execute this command on terminal (Windows):

```
keytool -v -list -keystore <jks file>
```

The alias is right in the beginning:

> `keytool -v -list -keystore keystore.jks`
>
> Enter keystore password:
>
> Keystore type: JKS
>
> Keystore type: JKS Keystore provider: SUN
>
> Your keystore contains 1 entry
>
> Alias name: **(*bunch of numbers*) *alias name***