# Import .key and .pem file to jks file and use in Java/Spring

Tags: java, ssl, keytool, pem, jks

I have been given the following key/cert from a service team to call their API over SSL, which I verfied thru curl command.

```
1. QA.test.key
2. QA.test.pem
```

**CURL command:**

```
curl --key QA.test.key --cert ./QA.test.pem -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d '{"pan":"1234567890123456", "client": " Application Name "}' https://test-qa.abc.com/tokenize
```

Now, to call the API in Java over https, do I need to do the following?

1. Create a self signed jks file
2. import the .key and .pem to new test.jks file?
3. Do the following

   ```
   public class TestApp {

   final static String KEYSTORE_PASSWORD = "testing";

   static
   {
       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "src/main/resources/test.jks");
       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);
       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",  "src/main/resources/test.jks");
       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
   }
   ```

   }

I am getting Invalid Certificate error while using the jks file, what would be the best way to create a jks file and import .key and .pem file for it to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a PKCS #12 file using OpenSSL utilities. Then you can specify this as your key store using the system properties.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in QA.test.pem -inkey QA.test.key -out test.pkcs12
```

This command will prompt for a password to encrypt the new PKCS #12 file. It may also prompt for the password that was used to encrypt `QA.test.key`, if any.

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=test.pkcs12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<whatever you entered when creating PKCS #12>
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
```

The `trustStore` properties are separate; they affect how to authenticate the server. If the server uses a certificate issued by a "real" CA, the necessary certificates should be present in the Java runtime already. Otherwise, you'll have to create an additional key store, which can be done using Java's `keytool` command.

Note that [Java 9 will use PKCS #12 files as the default](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/229) keystore type.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to create a jks is using the GUI tool portecle
http://portecle.sourceforge.net

Create JKS> import key/pair

You can also use keytool and OpenSSL. Check this [importing an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/importing-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-use-i)

Consider you need a keyStore for the client certificate and a trustStore for the certificates of your server. Usually the client certificate also contains them. If not, include also the certificates in the JKS (same file u other)

To invoke and send json you can use httpsURLconnection

```
  HttpsURLConnection conn =       (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
  conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
  conn.setMethod("POST");
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json"); 
  conn.connect();
  OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
  os.write(jsonString.getBytes());
  os.flush();
  os.close();
```

To create a socketFactory you could use

```
  SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getDefault();
  SSLSocketFactory sslFactory =  sc.getSocketFactory();
```

Here you have a full example (creating truststore and keystore with java code) [How can I use different certificates on specific connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection)

If you have problems with the SSL connection add

```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
```