# Can PEM files be used for Kafka security?

Tags: apache-kafka

The documentation at http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security describes the process of enabling security in Kafka.

It describes the certificates to be in JKS format. Is it possible to use PEM formatted certificates with Kafka?

-Yash

Comment: Just import PEM certificates into .jks store using `keytool`?

Answer (score 3):

You'll be able to use PEM in Kafka after 2.7.0 is released. Details [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-651+-+Support+PEM+format+for+SSL+certificates+and+private+key). Currently you can also use PKCS12.

Answer (score 0):

Update, since Kafka 2.7 PEM keys and certificates are supported.

You need to set `ssl.keystore.type`/`ssl.certificate.type` to `PEM` and then use `ssl.keystore.key`, `ssl.keystore.certificate.chain` and `ssl.truststore.certificates` to provide your keys and certificates.

---

Original answer

No you cannot directly use PEM certificates with Kafka.

This is not a Kafka restriction, it's just that all of the "mainstream" JVMs (HotSpot, OpenJDK, J9) use JKS.

See [Import .key and .pem file to jks file and use in Java/Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598919/import-key-and-pem-file-to-jks-file-and-use-in-java-spring)
for the required steps to import a PEM file into a JKS store.