# Netty 4 : Configure client certificates in SslContextBuilder

Tags: netty

I have a p12 format client ssl certificates.

How can I configure it in Netty in [SslContextBuilder](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslContextBuilder.html) class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the [.p12 to a Java Keystore.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224863/678116)

When starting your application, make sure you set the following system properties with the path to your Java Keystore (.jks) and given password:

- javax.net.ssl.keyStore
- javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword

Then, you can create a default SSLContext as shown below and add it to Netty's pipeline:

```
  SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getDefault();
  SSLEngine engine = ctx.createSSLEngine();
  engine.setUseClientMode(true);
  pipeline.addLast("sslHandler", new SslHandler(engine));
```