# Facing issues with Jenkins access ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: ssl, jenkins

I was hoping I can get some info on how to resolve this issue. I am new to jenkins and trying to setup a jenkins server.

After I enable SSL, I am unable to login to Jenkins. Chrome throws the error ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH.

Jenkins Version: jenkins-2.77-1.1

Steps followed:
1. Created a self signed SSL Cert.

2. Create Java keystore and imported the cert .

   `/bin/keytool \
   -keystore .keystore/cacerts \
   -import -alias jenkins -file ./ssl/cert.pem`
3. Updated /etc/sysconfig/jenkins

   `JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT="8443"
   JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE="/var/lib/jenkins/.keystore/cacerts"
   JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD="changeit"
   JENKINS_HTTPS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=""`
4. restarted jenkins.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

regards,

Comment: https://tehnoblog.org/google-chrome-error-err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch/

Answer (score 3):

Ok I was able to resolve this by creating a PKCS12 cert and adding that the to the java Keystore.

The following thread that has the steps: 
[How to import an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/how-to-import-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-u/8224863#8224863)

1. Created the PKCS12 cert as below.

   `openssl pkcs12 \
   -export -inkey ssl/key.pem \
   -in ssl/cert.pem \
   -out ssl/cert.p12 \
   -password pass:test`
2. Imported this cert to my java keystore.

    `/bin/keytool -importkeystore \
   -deststorepass changeit \
   -destkeypass changeit \
   -destkeystore .keystore/cacerts \
   -srckeystore ssl/cert.p12 \
   -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
   -srcstorepass test`

Comment: Facing the same issue and this answer can resolved the issue. Thank you !