# How to make REST Get request using certificate?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, client-certificates, spring-rest

I can query get request using curl:

```
curl -k --key some.key --cert some.crt --url "https://app.com:7078/subscribers/checkExists/1"
```

After that query I get `200 OK` Response. How I can achieve the same in Java? Using `Spring RestTemplate`?

I tried to disable certification checking by manuals in internet:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
            .build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
String urlOverHttps = "https://app.com:7078/subscribers/checkExists/1";
response = new RestTemplate(requestFactory).exchange(urlOverHttps, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
```

Also I tried it via `@Configuration`:

```
@Bean
public boolean disableSSLValidation() throws Exception {
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }
    }}, null);

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

And that code response me `400 Bad Request` error.

**UPD**

I also added my `some.crt` file to `%JAVA_HOME%\lib\security` and imported it with command - `keytool -import -alias ca -file some.crt -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit`

So, how can I provide my `some.crt` file in `GET` Request using `Spring RestTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your keys to the Java Key Store(JKS). See the answer found here about importing keys using the keytool:

[How to import an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/how-to-import-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-u)