# How to read EC Private key in java which is in .pem file format

Tags: java, security

How to read EC private key which is in. Pem file using JAVA. While reading I am getting the following exception.

**Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : version mismatch: (supported:     00, parsed:     01**

Actually my. Pem file contains private key in the following structure.

```
----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY ------
====+====+===
====+====+===
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: while i am trying to read EC Private Key which is in .pem format  using java,  I have got the following exception.Caused by: " java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : version mismatch: (supported:     00, parsed:     01)"

Answer (score 4):

From an EC PRIVATE KEY as requested (ex key.pem), I succeeded to import it in a java.security.KeyStore

1. transform private key from PEM => PKCS#8 DER

```sh
    openssl pkcs8 -in key.pem -inform PEM -topk8 -nocrypt -out key-pkcs8.der -outform DER
```

2. load it (jvm version java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.fc28.x86_64)

```java
 void loadPrivateKey(KeyStore ks, X509Certificate cert){
    File privKeyFile = new File("key-pkcs8.der");
    // read private key DER file
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(privKeyFile));
    byte[] privKeyBytes = new byte[(int)privKeyFile.length()];
    dis.read(privKeyBytes);
    dis.close();

    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    // decode private key
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyBytes);
    PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(privSpec);
    ks.setKeyEntry("key-alias", privKey, "password".toCharArray(), new Certificate[] {cert});
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why do we have to do step 1? Like what are the names of the standards of the to and from format?

Comment: the step 1 is to create the der file itself
standards are the one I find on my linux box using `man openssl`