# How to use certificate.crt and certificate.key with SSLServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

Following [Let's Encrypt's instructions](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/) on how to create a local certificate for testing purposes, I've made it to have a `certificate.crt` and `certificate.key` files. Now, how do I use them with a `SSLServerSocket`?
The only way I've used a `SSLServerSocket` before was with a keystore generated from `keytool`, and I did some research and didn't find any specific way to use the certificates generated by `openssl` with `SSLServerSocket`.

Comment: Import them into a PKCS#12 keystore using the OpenSSL tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUGGESTION:

Look at this link: [How to import an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/how-to-import-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-u)

1. Convert the existing cert to a PKCS12 using OpenSSL. A password is required when asked or the 2nd step will complain.

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export 
     -in [my_certificate.crt] -inkey [my_key.key] 
     -out [keystore.p12] 
     -name [new_alias] 
     -CAfile [my_ca_bundle.crt] -caname root
   ```
2. Convert the PKCS12 to a Java Keystore File.

   ```
   keytool -importkeystore 
     -deststorepass [new_keystore_pass] -destkeypass [new_key_pass] -destkeystore [keystore.jks] 
     -srckeystore [keystore.p12] -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass [pass_used_in_p12_keystore] 
     -alias [alias_used_in_p12_keystore]
   ```

Comment: So in the end I will still need a Java Keystore File? Those can be directly generate with keytool

Comment: @WashingtonA.Ramos Yes they can, and that's what you should have done to start with, instead of this detour through OpenSSL. See the JSSE Reference Guide.

Comment: Thank you. I'll stick with the implementation that uses the keytool-generated certificate, then.