# How to generate p12 file using pem and key file in Keytool

Tags: keytool, p12

I want to generate p12 file from existing pem and key file using keytool

Can anyone implemented it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import an existing X.509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/how-to-import-an-existing-x-509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias key -keystore something.keystore -dname "CN=YourCN,O=Thing,C=US" -validity 9999

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore something.keystore -destkeystore something.p12 -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass something
```

Comment: I do not have access to open ssl.. Want to create from keytool

Comment: there you go buddy -- if that doesn't work for you then you may need to reformat your existing key material