# Java keytool yields "keystore password was incorrect" when trying to import a PKCS12 to JKS

Tags: java, openssl, keytool, pkcs#12

I know this issue looks like a known one (many questions on this here), several bugs have been reported on different JDK versions and the situation has been very well summarized in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72501767

I happen to fall in what I think is another case, not yet answered. I must be doing something wrong, but I cannot see what.

I have a certificate and a private key in PEM format, and I want to create a JKS from that. I have read that the JKS format might not be needed anymore, but I do not control that part.

I process the files in command line. Things go like this, nothing special nor esoteric:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.crt -passout pass:changeit -inkey pkey.key -out keystore.p12

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore  keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass changeit -deststorepass changeit -destkeystore keystore.jks
```

I get:

```
Importing keystore keystore.p12 to keystore.jks...
keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
```

Now, the thing is that I have tried that with many versions of the JDK, and it never succeeds.

Facts:

- the input files are both correct (checked with `openssl x509 -in cert.crt -text -noout` and `openssl rsa -in pkey.key -text -noout`)
- the generated PKCS12 can be checked with openssl : `openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -info -noout -passin pass:changeit`
- Ubuntu 22.04, openssl v3 (`OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`)

From that point, I thought I stumbled on the known JDK issue.

I have tried with those versions, *all fail with the exact same message*:

- openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19
- openjdk version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19
- openjdk version "18-ea" 2022-03-22

Finally, I could also try with the following combo: openssl 1.1.1n + openjdk 11.0.15, yields same error.
All the JDK I have tried are above version 11.0.12.

I am stuck and desperate, have spent far too much time on this.
(For the record, I try to set up the bitnami keycloak chart with an existing secret containing PEM certificates, and the container responsible for importing it fails. I have tried to do the same thing manually, and here I am).

Edit:

Thanks dave_thompson_085 for the suggestion. Here is the backtrace of the keytool error:

```
java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2158)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:226)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1503)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.loadSourceKeyStore(Main.java:2319)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1234)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:416)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:409)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: Empty issuer DN not allowed in X509Certificates
```

and the output of openssl pkcs12 -info:

```
MAC: sha256, Iteration 2048
MAC length: 32, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Encrypted data: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 2048, PRF hmacWithSHA256
Certificate bag
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 2048, PRF hmacWithSHA256
```

I am going to follow the path shown by that evil-looking `java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: Empty issuer DN not allowed in X509Certificates` message...

Comment: Have you tried `-srcstorepass pass:changeit`?

Comment: Add `-J-showversion -v` to the `keytool -importkeystore` command(s) to confirm what you're running and get more complete error info (especially the 'Caused by:' section of the stacktrace). And confirm the metadata shown by `openssl pkcs12 -info -noout` especially if it is PBES2, PBKDF2, and hmacwithSHA256.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thank you for your response. This makes me think I have also seen this:
https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/wikis/display/CEKB/Could+not+load+keystore%3A+keystore+password+was+incorrect+with+java+1.8.301+for+Domibus+running+on+open+jdk
I have tried adding ```-J-Dkeystore.pkcs12.legacy```, but this did not work.
I am updating the question with the output of your commands.

Comment: Okay, stacktrace shows this is NOT a password/encryption problem such as the one in the previous Q; **it's the _input_ certificate(s?)** (which OpenSSL doesn't check strictly), and indeed you need to look there. Someone might have confused the fact that (at least for SSL/TLS) a leaf cert can have _Subject_ empty if SAN is present, but not _Issuer_, and if this is selfsigned Issuer and Subject must be the same. `keystore.pkcs12.legacy` only matters when Java/keytool is _creating_ the PKCS12, not reading it.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The certificates involved are generated by cert-manager, from a self-signed issuer. I'm going to dig from there : https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/3634

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by @dave_thompson_085, I could use the `-J-showversion` flag to the `keytool -importkeystore` command, and get a useful message from that Java tool.

As you can see from the backtrace in my post, the resulting message `keystore password was incorrect` was the result of a deeper `Empty issuer DN not allowed in X509Certificates` exception... The error message was very misleading and made me lose time.

My problem came from how the issuer for my keycloak certificate was declared. I have referred to the [cert-manager documentation](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/selfsigned/#bootstrapping-ca-issuers), fixed my issue, and keycloak finally accepted my PEM as input to create a keystore.

Thanks and best regards,

Pierre