self-signed SSL cert bad password
When starting Spring application, it fails with bad password when accessing the pfx file for SSL.
I have successfully opened the pfx file in IntelliJ plug-in with the same password that is stored in application.yaml,
Hopefully someone can see my mistake ...
updates
Spring is using Java 21
PFX made with OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)
OpenSSL info
openssl pkcs12 -in MyComputer.pfx -info -noout
Enter Import Password:
MAC: sha256, Iteration 2048
MAC length: 32, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Encrypted data: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 2048, PRF hmacWithSHA256
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 2048, PRF hmacWithSHA256

application.yaml
server:
  port: 8043
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: classpath:keystore/${COMPUTERNAME}.pfx
    key-store-password: secure
    key-alias: ${COMPUTERNAME}

excerpt from startup log
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create key store: Could not load store from 'classpath:keystore/XXXXXX.pfx'
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.jks.JksSslStoreBundle.createKeyStore(JksSslStoreBundle.java:94) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.jks.JksSslStoreBundle.<init>(JksSslStoreBundle.java:57) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerSslBundle.createJksKeyStoreBundle(WebServerSslBundle.java:90) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerSslBundle.createKeyStore(WebServerSslBundle.java:189) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerSslBundle.createStoreBundle(WebServerSslBundle.java:179) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerSslBundle.get(WebServerSslBundle.java:174) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.getSslBundle(AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.java:225) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeSsl(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:373) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeConnector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:349) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:210) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:188) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load store from 'classpath:keystore/XXXXXX.pfx'
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.jks.JksSslStoreBundle.loadKeyStore(JksSslStoreBundle.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.jks.JksSslStoreBundle.createKeyStore(JksSslStoreBundle.java:89) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2097) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:228) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1500) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.jks.JksSslStoreBundle.loadKeyStore(JksSslStoreBundle.java:119) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    ... 23 common frames omitted


What version(s) of Java, and what created the PKCS12? In the last few years many things have (finally!) been updated to use PBES2 encryption in PKCS12 rather than the long-conventional pbewithsha1and3-keytripledes and some versions of Java didn't correctly handle PBES2 if it used PBKDF2 with anything but HMAC-SHA1 -- and some things now use it with HMAC-SHA256. If you have (any, even older) OpenSSL available, openssl pkcs12 -in file -info -noout (and the pw) should show you the MAC and encryption parameters. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/72412346/

@dave_thompson_085 Updated post with answers to your questions.  Not sure where to go from here.

Okay, that file is indeed PBES2-with-HMAC-SHA256 but Java 21 should not be affected by the bug. See if keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore existing -destkeystore throwaway successfully copies it (which involves decrypting and re-encrypting). Are you actually using secure (which of course isn't); if not does it contain any non-ASCII character, especially an accented letter? Try keytool with -srcstorepass xxx on command line, and without so it prompts, and maybe also -srcstorepass in a script file; these might encode (some) characters differently.

Oh, and just to confirm, when creating with openssl pkcs12 -export you did NOT use -twopass? That creates a split Java cannot handle. (Java _can _ handle keybag different from other two, but not MAC different from other two.)
