# SSL certificate issue when deploying a rest api

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, vps

In localhost, with an auto-generate certificate, I have access to my API in HTTPS.
On the other hand, on my VPS, with the certificate provided by my host, I get errors.
I guess the problem must come from the conversion of the certificate provided in .cer to the version in .p12, since my code remains unchanged from the localhost version and in the version on the VPS.

Here are the errors generated

> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1075)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:234)
> ... 18 more
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alias name [springboot] does not identify a key entry
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:234)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1313)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1072)
> ... 20 more
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [springboot] does not identify a key entry
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:337)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105)

And here is the HTTPS configuration in spring-boot

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=springboot
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:files/cert/springboot-mooddraw-com.p12
#server.ssl.key-store=classpath:files/cert/springboot-localhost.p12
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12
server.ssl.key-store-password=cxcxvd
server.ssl.key-password=cxcxvd
```

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: "Alias name [springboot] does not identify a key entry"

Comment: Thanks,
I can read but it doesn't tell me the solution.
When converting the certificate I gave springboot as an alias using the following command:

`keytool -import -alias springboot -file myCertificate.crt -keystore springboot.p12 -storepass password`

And when registering in the cacerts of the server I also put springboot as an alias using the following command:

`keytool -importcert -file myCertificate.crt -alias springboot -keystore $JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

And yet I have an unrecognized alias error so where can I find the correct alias?

Comment: Which version of springboot are you using?

Comment: What is missing is the **key**. You only put the certificate. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224863/12763954) for an example on how to create a .p12 store with openssl containing both a key and a certificate.

Comment: Thank you Olivier, Indeed, by recreating the .p12 according to the procedure linked to your message, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the statement `server.ssl.key-alias=springboot` with `server.ssl.keyAlias=springboot`. If you also face the issue with key store type then replace the `server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12` with `server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12`.