# How to import two .pem into single .p12 keystore?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have two certs in pem format:

- Server SSL Cert from Let's Encrypt
- Login cert (cert + private key) from MongoDB atlas

When both are imported to single keystore, mongo driver throws:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8000 (AtlasError): 'certificate validation failed' on server ac-9g18w0d-shard-00-02.rrfpnfg.mongodb.net:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0, "errmsg": "certificate validation failed", "code": 8000, "codeName": "AtlasError"}
```

When I keep them in different key-stores, it works fine.

To import Let's Encrypt cert I used this guide:
https://blog.ordina-jworks.io/security/2019/08/14/Using-Lets-Encrypt-Certificates-In-Java.html

For MongoAtlas I was using this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54208558

Also, I'm loading those certs as spring SSL bundle from single key-store:

```
spring:
  ssl:
    bundle:
      jks:
        server:
          key:
            alias: server
          keystore:
            location: keystore.p12
            password: ${PASSWORD}
            type: PKCS12
        database:
          key:
            alias: mongodb
          keystore:
            location: keystore.p12
            password: ${PASSWORD}
            type: PKCS12
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: <mongo+srv uri>
      ssl:
        enabled: true
        bundle: database
```

But every time I got mentioned earlier error. At this point, I'm not sure why it is not working with single key-store. Can you guys point me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.